# Extending root partition on /dev/vda with space on /dev/vdb

Tags: server, 20.04, vps, virtual-file-system

I have a VPS which has this drive structure:

[image: drive structure]

Is it possible to extend `vda` to take all space (375G) and remove `vdb`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two disks here, `vda` and `vdb`, you can of course span the two disks by a `RAID 0` but this will prevent you booting ([see here](https://superuser.com/a/1505694/1032239)), so if you can have your boot partition on a third disk and do some tinkering with grub it may work

Comment: I think it is on OpenStack platform. No access to any disk to do any stuffs.